# How to fix 'Invalid calling object'

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to upload an image in my web application. But I get the error stated as the title. Please see my code below.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="file" id="image" />
        </div>
        <button id="upload">Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Ajax**

```
$('#upload').click(function () {

     var fileUpload = $("#image").get(0).files;
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Insert',
        data: {
          Name: 'Test',
          floor: '6th',
          capacity: '3',
          file: fileUpload[0]
         },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
             alert("SUCCESS!");
        }, error: function(){
             alert("ERROR");
        }
        });
    });
```

Thank you

Comment: why you are not using form submit?

Comment: To upload files you need formData object check [jQuery: How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8758614/387194)

Comment: Thank you jcubic! You are a true life saver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)